# navigateByURL with hashtag lands in wrong position - Angular routerLink inside router-outlet

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]A link to switch a page between router-outlet doesn't work well, it moves to a correct page but it lands in the middle of the page (somewhere under router-outlet) instead of header where I've set focus.

- RouterLink works between outside of router-outlet(navigation) and router-outlet.
- If I remove fragment/focusDirective, it lands on top on the page, but I need to have fragment in order for screen reader to read up the header.
- Header becomes focused (tested with NerdeFocus chrome extension) when the page has been rendered, so focus function seems working
- I tried to add scrollIntoView function in app component, but it didn't help
- I'm using Angular11

app.ts

```
<nav class="col-lg-3">
....
</nav>

<div class="col-lg-9">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'b',
    component: BComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    useHash: true,
    relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'
}),
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Component A html

```
<a (click)="onEditMode($event)">Edit</a>
```

Component A ts

```
onEditMode(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.router.navigateByUrl('componentB#header');
}
```

Component B html

```
<h1 id="header" tabindex="-1" appFocusFragment>Header</h1>
```

focusFragment

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocusFragment]'
})

export class FocusFragmentDirective implements AfterViewInit{
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
      const anchor = document.querySelector<HTMLAnchorElement>(`#${fragment}`);
      if (fragment && anchor) {
        anchor.scrollIntoView();
        anchor.focus();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Sorry about my bad explanation and English, please kindly let me know if more information is needed.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I'm visualizing the behavior you describe correctly without a reproducible example but it almost sounds like somewhere the `scroll-margin-top` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top) is being invoked or perhaps you may need to designate the offset manually. Would know better with an example to visually see the issue and troubleshoot though.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!
I've attached a picture, does it help to explain the issue visually...?

Comment: So expectation is for the orange line (viewport) to align with the top of the `id="header"` element's top? Without seeing the DOM flow another quick guess would be simply add the params to your call on `scrollIntoView` eg; `anchor.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });`

Comment: I would like to show `id="header"` element on the top of the viewport like normal website(inside orange line). (Sorry about the bad explanation.. I'm frustrated myself not being able to explain well.)
I tried adding params inside `scrolltoView` but unfortunately didn't help.. (this directive works without params when a link is on navigation)

Comment: Ya then this one is kind of tough to diagnose with only the info provided. Personally I don't see anything immediately at fault so I'd have to see it in action, sorry.

Comment: @ChrisW. I understand and I'm sorry I can't share the link. Thank you so much anyways for trying to help me.